# Not able to assign custom profile to user

Tags: licenses, developer-edition, custom-profile

Was trying to implement something for that I created a custom Profile from cloning Sytem Admin and now I want to assign that profile to two Users. Assigned to one of the users but not able to see that profile under any of the existing licenses for the other user.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you check you have enough licenses in your org which is assigned to that profile.

Comment: I checked and yes I have assigned the Salesforce License which we only get 2 in Developer org and both are used. What are the changes I can perform now to accomplish the above mention task

Comment: Yes as you don't have enough Number of licenses you are not able to assign the profile to another user.

Comment: Yes I got that but which license should I assign to the custom profile, any help on that?

Comment: It depends on the functionality which you want to achieve and profile which you clone. Please refer the below [Article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_available.htm&type=5) for the same.

Comment: Thank you that helped

Answer (score 1):

As you will be having only two licenses with Salesforce License you wont be able to assign this to more than 1 user. Because one is the system admin user which you might me using and other license is what you have assigned  to user1.